# Listing Number one records in a Simple SQL Database.

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a small database with four tables arranged as follows;

TABLE band_members COLUMNS: band_id(PK), name, dob, country, sex

TABLE bands        COLUMNS : band_id(PK), band_name

TABLE cds          COLUMNS : cd_id(PK), rdate, title, position, weeks

TABLE releases     COLUMNS : cd_id, band_id

What I'm trying to do is display the name of the band and the number of times they've had a number one record. (i.e. position = '1')

This is the code I've tried that doesn't seem to be working:

```
SELECT band_name
FROM cds
JOIN releases ON cds.cd_id = releases.cd_id
JOIN bands ON releases.band_id = bands.band_id
GROUP BY (position='1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably have a bandmembers_band table, as you are most likely eventually have to deal with band members that are part of multiple bands - this happens often these days.

To answer:

```
SELECT band_name, count(cds.cd_id)
FROM (select cds.cd_id, cds.position from cds where cds.position = 1 group by cds.cd_id)
JOIN releases ON cds.cd_id = releases.cd_id
JOIN bands ON releases.band_id = bands.band_id
GROUP BY band_name
having count(cds.cd_id) > 0
```

(pseudo - may work out of the box)

Comment: Thanks. The code given works, but gives me twice the count it should be displaying. Do you think it might be something to do with the joins I've used?

Comment: See my updated code.  It could be that the cd is on the chart at position one for more than a week, which will likely trigger that).  Also, a band with multiple number one albums will also trigger that condition.  Limit both in sub-queries - as I have done in the cds)

Comment: I'm such an idiot. turns out my releases table had duplicate data. That was the only data i didn't check... Thank You for your help.